# Missing Imports [Django] [Pip External Packages]

Tags: python, django, pip

I started using django for the first time today and I have been encountering one issue

I want to use the **PDFNetPython3** library for my project in Django framework.
I ran the command pip install PDFNetPython3 and it is says its already installed, however Django isn't able to resolve the import

**Error/Warning**

```
Import "PDFNetPython3" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

This is the line below being shown as **unresolved import**.

```
from PDFNetPython3 import PDFDoc, Optimizer, SDFDoc, PDFNet
```

**views.py**

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def compress(request):
    return render(request, 'compress.html')

def showName(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       user_initial_pdf = request.POST['user_initial_pdf']
       from PDFNetPython3 import PDFDoc, Optimizer, SDFDoc, PDFNet
       return HttpResponse("ok")
```

###### Python Version - 3.9.7

###### Django Version - 4.0.1

Please note : I havent created any virtual environment as of now cause I just started django and found out its a good practice to do so, can it be the cause django not able to resolve the library through pip ?

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Pylance is a linter that is used in VSCode's Python extension. Make sure that VSCode is using the proper Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks it seems vscode was indeed on the wrong python version interpreter.